# Photon selfenergy diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman, feynmf, feynmp

I am typing my project using LaTeX, I need to insert a photon self-energy diagram with symmetric moments in centre alignment

This is what I need:
[image: diagram]

Please help me...

Comment: Please do not post fragments of code but rather try to provide a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: I edited the question@TeXnician

Comment: You have removed the code altogether, didn't you? Well, with MWE I referred to something along the lines of [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/124577). It is welcomed to have such a code example in the question to help us help you. But as you already got an answer, maybe someone will try to make a TikZ solution up from scratch…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TikZ-Feynman can do it certainly.

Here is Asymptote code.

http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
import feynman;
unitsize(0.75cm);
currentpen = linewidth(1bp);
photonamplitude=0.2;
draw(scale(2)*Label("$p,a$",Relative(.3),2*RightSide),photon((-5,0)--(0,0),width=1.3),Arrow(TeXHead,position=Relative(0.45),size=4));
draw(scale(2)*Label("$p,a$",Relative(.7),5*RightSide),photon((5,0)--(10,0),width=1.3),Arrow(TeXHead,position=Relative(0.45),size=4));
draw(scale(2)*Label("$q+p/2$",LeftSide),(0,0){dir(90)}..{dir(-90)}(5,0),Arrow(TeXHead,position=Relative(0.4),size=3));
draw(scale(2)*Label("$q-p/2$",LeftSide),(5,0){dir(-90)}..{dir(90)}(0,0),Arrow(TeXHead,position=Relative(0.6),size=3));
```

[image]

With https://www.overleaf.com/,

[image]

https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f140170cae5be0001d831aa

Comment: I don't get diagram by using this code,Iam using overleaf latex writer@user213378

Comment: @ROBINRAJ See edited answer.

Comment: I am unable to click this link "https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f140170cae5be0001d831aa" I am using the basic version of overleaf @user213378

Comment: @ROBINRAJ You can open [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/2d-graphics-with-asymptote/zppdrrhdszhr) or https://www.overleaf.com/6581438472kbmkvdwtwbvk. Code is available.

Comment: Thanks it helps@user213378

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tikz-feynman`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\newcommand{\virgola}{\smash{\raisebox{0.1ex}{,}}}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- [boson,edge label'=\(p\virgola a\),charged boson] b
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5,edge label'=\(\scriptstyle q+\frac{p}{2}\)] c
-- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5, edge label'=\(\scriptstyle q-\frac{p}{2}\)] b,
c -- [boson,edge label'=\(p\virgola a\),charged boson] d,
};

\end{document}
```

[image]